# How to Get Current Directory Name in mod_rewrite(.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my servers I use the following rewrite request:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /dir_name/kip_dashboard.php?userID=$1 [L]
```

I am using same `.htaccess` file in two different location (localhost & server).

Ex.

```
http://localhost/dir_l/      \\Localhost
http://server.com/dir_ser/   \\Server
```

How can I get the current directory automatically in `.htaccess.`

```
(Ex: RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /{HTTP_DIRECTORY}kip_dashboard.php?userID=$1 [L])
```

like this.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RewriteBase directive.

By setting on `\\Localhost`

```
RewriteBase /dir_l
```

and on `\\Server`

```
RewriteBase /dir_ser
```

This will strip the prefix for all next redirection rewrite and happen it when rewrite has been done, so you don't have to specify the directory in the rewrite itself.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: Thanks for your Reply... but this is not what exactly i want... you are saying to set base directory. but i could'nt use the same file in both place.. i might use two different files. In PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] will return the Domain name right? like that can we get the Directory name of the HtAccess file?

Comment: Did you try to use the relative addressing then ? I mean without the first `/` : `RewriteRule profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ kip_dashboard.php?userID=$1 [L]`